# Is there any common intent agreement for cryptocurrency transfer?

Tags: android, android-intent, ethereum, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

There is list of common Android intents, introduced by Google:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common

In my app i need to initiate cryptocurrency transfer. Is there any intent format (action, extras) for it supported by the most popular Android apps?

To be more detailed i need to initiate Ethereum transfer:

- to address
- amount (in Wei or any Ether denomination)
- payload (data) as hex string
- gasLimit (optional)
- gasPrice (optional)

Any better way to do it? For now it seems like navigating to "myetherwallet.com" with prefilled fields is the best alternative.

Comment: My guess is that you will be better served by coming up with a list of apps and contacting their developers, asking if any of them support an `Intent`-based API such as this.

Comment: yes, i've been thinking about it but i just want to make sure there is no some agreement already.